# Selecting rows based on status

Tags: python, pandas

I have this dataframe: https://www.kaggle.com/mpwolke/cusersmarildownloadsallcsv

I want to select only those countries whose status has changed over the year. I am clueless as to how can I to achieve this. Can someone please help me.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with `groupby filter`.

```
df = df.groupby('country_territory').filter(lambda x: x['status'].nunique() > 1)
```

Comment: This is what i was looking for Thank you soo much.